# Get embedded media in the content of a post

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to the all the images that were inserted to a post so I can display them all in a lightbox if one of them is clicked, more or less like Exposure does (https://wwf.exposure.co/better-choices-at-the-great-barrier-reef#view:mc42bisb7dsu4n29mm6e4txqy6bqehfrmo9a), but cannot find anyway to get the images that were inserted and NOT attached.

I found `get_embedded_media()` in the codex but has been deprecated and apparently only worked for video and sound.

Cannot found any away of doing this.

Ideas?

Comment: `get_attached_media()` should work for this as long as you're using the Wordpress media uploader to embed the images. These should be attached to the post. Otherwise, you should be able to scrape the post using a `the_content` filter with a low priority and get the image tags embedded in it.

Comment: @cpilko the thing is that no, the media is already uploaded and will always be like that, so yeah, I think I have to parse `the_content` to get them then, do you have any idea how?